# MySQL: List of connected users in a forum-like website?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forum

Hello and sorry for the unclear title.

Basically, I want to do (in the idea of learning PHP) simple forum-like website.
I have already created login and registration interface, but now I would like to be able to display a list of currently logged users.

I already have a user table containing their ID, but do I also need to add a 'IsConnect' field or do I need to create another table containing the ID of the currently connected users?

Thank's !

Comment: You can add a "last action" field (timestamp) to the user table, and if it's within X minutes from now (say 5 minutes), assume they're online. You'll need to update that field on each page load or action though.

Comment: You could also trigger an AJAX request in the background every minute or so to keep the last action time up to date as long as the user has a browser open.

Comment: It's equivalent to add a 'connect' field which is True when the user is logged and False when the user quit (or with a timestamp delay yes) no ?